# issue while logging graphql info object

Tags: logging, graphql, apollo

In each apollo graphql resolver we have the following line:

`logger.info(resolverName, { parent, args, info });`

I've noticed that for some calls, the log doesn't appear in our logging service (datadog) and when we remove the `info` parameter it does appear.

What can cause this issue when trying to log the info param?

Comment: Maybe it contains too much information or even cyclic references? If so, as a workaround you could try to first map it to a smaller object or serialize it to a string?

Comment: Probably a dumb question but have you just tried doing a basic console.log()? i.e, `console.log(resolverName, { parent, args, info })` as a debugging mechanism to see if the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: There is no problem with doing `npm start` and doing console.log(), if I remove the info parameter everything works well.